# Print a text file using printer object in .net

Tags: .net, printing, dos

I am creating one utility to print text file in vb.net using printer object in dotmetrilx printer. When we print any text file using our application it took around 10 sec to print 25 lines. And when we print same file to print using dos command it took around 5 sec. So my question is how to improve performance in our application. Sample code is given below:

```
Using Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.Printing.Compatibility.VB6;
Printer..FontName = "Courier New"
objPrinter.FontSize = 8;
objPrinter.Print(sb.ToString());
```

and we are using following DOS command to print the text fine.

```
print c:\abc.txt \d:printername
```

Please guide me how to do that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the printers Object..

here is a sample Printing Class that i use to print simple Barcoded tags on a lable printer.

Sample Code Here,

Imports System.Drawing
Namespace Printers

```
Public Class PrintDocument
    Private WithEvents _PrintDialog As New System.Windows.Forms.PrintDialog
    Private _PrinterObject As New System.Printing.LocalPrintServer
    Private Regfunctions As New DataFunctions.Regfunctions.Regfunctions
    Private _PrinterName As DataFunctions.Regfunctions.Regfunctions.Regkeys
    Private WithEvents _PrintItem As Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument
    Public Event PrintPage(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs)

    Public Sub New(ByVal PrinterID As String)
        _PrinterName = Regfunctions.Load(DataFunctions.Regfunctions.Regfunctions.Reg_type.Current_Config, DataFunctions.Regfunctions.Regfunctions.KeyRegloc & "\Printers", PrinterID, _PrinterObject.DefaultPrintQueue.FullName)
        _PrintDialog.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = _PrinterName.KeyVal
    End Sub

    Public Function ShowDialog() As Windows.Forms.DialogResult
        Dim TmpResult As Windows.Forms.DialogResult
        TmpResult = _PrintDialog.ShowDialog()
        _PrinterName.KeyVal = _PrintDialog.PrinterSettings.PrinterName
        Regfunctions.Save(_PrinterName)
        Return TmpResult
    End Function

    Public Function Print() As Windows.Forms.DialogResult
        _PrintItem = New Printing.PrintDocument
        _PrintItem.PrinterSettings = _PrintDialog.PrinterSettings
        _PrintItem.Print()
    End Function

    Private Sub _PrintItem_PrintPage(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles _PrintItem.PrintPage
        RaiseEvent PrintPage(sender, e)
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class PrintTags
    Private _BarcodeNo As String
    Private _DateString As String
    Private _PartNO As String
    Private _Station As String
    Private _BarCode As Image
    Private Barcodes As New Barcodes.BarcodeModule

    Public Sub PrintTag(ByVal BarcodeNo As String, ByVal DateStr As String, ByVal PartNO As String, ByVal Station As String)
        Dim TmpRec As New Rectangle
        TmpRec.Width = 280
        TmpRec.Height = 100


        _BarcodeNo = BarcodeNo
        _DateString = DateStr
        _PartNO = PartNO
        _Station = Station
        _BarCode = Barcodes.NewBarcode(_BarcodeNo, TmpRec)

        Dim TmpPrinter As New Printers.PrintDocument("BCPrinter")
        AddHandler TmpPrinter.PrintPage, AddressOf PrintTheTag
        TmpPrinter.Print()
    End Sub

    Private Sub PrintTheTag(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs)
        Dim canvas As Graphics = e.Graphics
        Dim Font1 As New Font("Arial", 24, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Pixel)
        canvas.DrawString(_Station, Font1, Brushes.Black, 10, 10)
        canvas.DrawString(_BarcodeNo, Font1, Brushes.Black, 10, 50)
        canvas.DrawString(_PartNO, Font1, Brushes.Black, 10, 90)
        canvas.DrawString(_DateString, Font1, Brushes.Black, 10, 130)
        canvas.DrawImage(_BarCode, 0, 180, 280, 100)
    End Sub

End Class
```

End Namespace

then where ever i need to print the tag i use..

Code here,

Private TagPrint As New Printers.Printers.PrintTags

```
    TagPrint.PrintTag(Fonumber, Date.Now.ToString, Part, StationName)
```